# No such file or directoy - but file exists

Tags: windows, screen

I am using ubuntu on windows and I am trying to use the screen command to execute a python  script

I have navigated to the current working directory and the .py file exists.

The command I am trying to run is `~$ screen python streaming.py`

However I get an error:

```
Cannot Execute Python : No such file or directoy.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Screen First, Then run the command, So :

`screen`

Then , Navigate to the Directory, and :

`python streaming.py`

Then (Ctrl+a) + d to Detach the screen

**OR:**

`screen python /complete/path/to/streaming.py`